# How to prevent lxml prom compacting elements?

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization, lxml, elementtree

Having following Python code:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.XML("<a><b></b></a>")
>>> etree.tostring(root)
'<a><b/></a>'
```

How can I force lxml to use "long" version?

Like

```
>>> etree.tostring(root)
'<a><b></b></a>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> html = lxml.html.fromstring('<a><b></b></a>')
>>> lxml.html.tostring(html)
'<a><b></b></a>'
```

Mixing works as well:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import lxml.html
>>> xml = etree.XML('<a><b/></a>')
>>> lxml.html.tostring(xml)
'<a><b></b></a>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to? Both are equivalent in terms of XML's data model.

Comment: Yes, but in case of testing (which is what I do), string representation of the model might matter.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation

```
    from lxml import etree
    xml = etree.XML('<a><b/></a>')
    etree.tostring(xml, method='html')
    '<a><b></b></a>'
```